# Debug View Hierarchy: [NSConcreteValue doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11, xcode9, view-debugging

I'm trying to debug view hierarchy on my device (iPhone X, iOS 11.1) attached to the debugger (Xcode 9.1). However, even though the wireframes of the views are drawn, no actual view content is drawn and I'm getting exceptions printed to the console instead:

```
2017-12-03 00:34:24.326037+0300 MyApp[40961:10090136] -[NSConcreteValue doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d4322260
2017-12-03 00:34:24.408071+0300 MyApp[40961:10090136] -[NSCoder(CACoderAdditions) CA_encodeObject:forKey:conditional:]: ignoring exception -[NSConcreteValue doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d4322260
```

Here is a screenshot from the view debugger, demonstrating the issue:

[image]

In view debugger, "Wireframes and contents" option is selected. If I select only contents, I get a blank view. How can I debug my view?

Comment: Have you filed a bug at bugreport.apple.com ?